# Get installation path of a software(Acrobat Reader) using winreg

Tags: python-3.x, winreg

I need to find the installation path of Acrobat Reader installed in the client system like

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe

I'm getting the following using wingreg

```
from winreg import OpenKey, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, QueryValueEx
key = OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\WOW6432Node\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\DC\InstallPath", 0)
QueryValueEx(key, '')[0]
```

> 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Acrobat Reader DC\\Reader'

1. How can I get the full path including AcroRd32.exe ?
2. How I can find if a different version of Acrobat is installed?

Comment: All the apps in Wow6432Node Registry Key should be 32 bit, https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/registry-wow6432-node.html